# index page not show after login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i have the process page for login, i can connected to DB and also can check the username and password.

but after that, i cant show the index page after login success.This is my code:

```
$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV,_ACCID,_PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("qdbase",$dbc) or die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());

    switch(postVar('action')) {
                    case 'submitlogin' :
                    submitlogin(postVar('loguser'),postVar('logpass'));
                    break;
    }
    function submitlogin($loguser,$logpass){
    if(isset($loguser, $logpass)) {
        ob_start();
        // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $myusername = stripslashes($loguser);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($logpass);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername,$dbc);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword, $dbc);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='$myusername' AND password=('$mypassword')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $dbc);
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1){
            // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
            session_register("admin");
            session_register("password");
            $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
            header("location:index1.php");
        }
        else {
            $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
            header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
        }
  //      ob_end_flush();
    }
    else {
        header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
    }
    mysql_close($dbc);
    ob_end_flush();
    }
```

can you help me to resolve this problem?

---

### EDIT

i get confusing in this part from index1.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if(!session_is_registered("admin")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>
```

and this part from login.php, because i think they unsyncronize:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            session_register("admin");
            session_register("password");

            $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;

            header("location:index1.php");
        }
```

i'm just have user and password, where is the `admin` come from? bcoz from this i get:

```
 PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ADMIN - assumed 'ADMIN' in /var/www/html/index1.php on line 12
```

Comment: Did you get any error or warning?

Comment: no error it shows 200.OK

Comment: Any PHP error? Is your `error_reporting()` verbose enough? `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_USER_NOTICE)`

Comment: After login did you get any message or on which page you get redirect?

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/process1.php on line 591. actually at mysql_close($dbc);

Comment: just put ob_end_flush() after my_close($dbc);

Comment: Do you see a blank page? Can you right clicke and view source and can u see anything?

Comment: Where your connection to Mysql? I don't see the $dbc variable

Comment: @Shoban: no, it still stuck in login page

Comment: that `PHP Notice` error is because `ADMIN` is not in quotes within `define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']);` needs to be `define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['name']);`

Comment: yeah..i've cleared all..that is happen because i have downloaded from some site.;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your messing up your real escapes.

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($dbc, $myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($dbc, $mypassword);
```

Should be

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername, $dbc);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword, $dbc);
```

heres the doc block:

```
string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

@source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

And

```
$result=mysql_query($dbc, $sql);
```

Should Be

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc);
```

---

Update #1

Not promising this will work be just gone threw your code and cleaned it up, removed some stuff and added some stuff:

```
if(false === ($dbc = mysql_connect(_SRV,_ACCID,_PWD) die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
if(false === mysql_select_db("qdbase",$dbc)) die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());


switch(postVar('action'))
{
    case 'submitlogin':
        submitlogin(postVar('loguser'),postVar('logpass'));
            mysql_close($dbc);
            exit; //Flushing the headers
    break;
}

function submitlogin($loguser,$logpass)
{
    if(isset($loguser, $logpass))
    {
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($loguser));
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($logpass));

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='%s' AND password=('%s')",$myusername,$mypassword);

        if(false === ($result = mysql_query($sql))
        {
            //Show Database query error and die()
        }

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            session_register("admin");
            session_register("password");

            $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;

            header("location:index1.php");
        }else
        {
            header("location:login.php?msg=" . urlencode("Wrong Username or Password. Please retry"));
        }
    }else{
        header("location:login.php?msg=" . urlencode("Please enter some username and password"));
    }
}
```

Comment: still same sir. the result is not a query after i echo the $sql. but it show html code of login.php

Comment: may be it can works because the result at XHR shows html script of index1.php page. but why the page not show?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your program have any output before the header() call? If your program has sent some output (even a single whitespace) the header call won't work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php